# variable value gets null in retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a fragment which has an adapter. I am using retrofit to fetch data from web

my frangment

```
class MyTransactionFragment : Fragment() {
    val disposable = CompositeDisposable()
    var transactionDetailList:ArrayList<TransactionData>? = null
    private var mApiSocket: ApiSocket? = null
    private var mRecyclerView:RecyclerView? = null
    var adapter:TransactionAdapter? = null
    companion object {
        val TAG = ItemFragment::class.java.simpleName!!
        fun newInstance(transactionPojo: TransactionPojo): MyTransactionFragment {
            val fragment = MyTransactionFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putSerializable(Constants.TRANSACTIONS, transactionPojo)
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_transaction, container, false)
        mApiSocket = Utils().getApiSocket(activity!!)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        view.mRecyclerViewTransaction.layoutManager = layoutManager
        view.mRecyclerViewTransaction.setHasFixedSize(true)
        if (arguments!=null && arguments!!.getSerializable(Constants.TRANSACTIONS) != null){
            val transactionPojo = arguments!!.getSerializable(Constants.TRANSACTIONS) as TransactionPojo
            transactionDetailList = ArrayList(transactionPojo.transactions.data)
            adapter = TransactionAdapter(transactionDetailList, activity!!,disposable)
            view.mRecyclerViewTransaction.adapter = adapter
            mRecyclerView = view.mRecyclerViewTransaction
            val scrollListener = object : EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(layoutManager) {
                override fun onLoadMore(page: Int, totalItemsCount: Int, view: RecyclerView) {
                    disposable.add(mApiSocket!!.transaction(""+page+1)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(MyTransactionFragment()::onResponse,MyTransactionFragment()::onError))
                }
            }
            view.mRecyclerViewTransaction.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
        }
        return view
    }

    private fun onResponse(transactionPojo: TransactionPojo){
        transactionDetailList = ArrayList(transactionPojo.transactions.data)
        adapter!!.addData(transactionDetailList)  //here adapter variable gets null Why
    }

    fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        Log.e("TransactionFragment", e.toString())
        if (e is NoNetWorkException) {
            Utils().showSnackBar(activity!!, "No Network connection")
        } else
            Utils().showSnackBar(activity!!, "Something went wrong please try again later")
        Utils().hideProgress()
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        disposable.dispose()
    }

}
```

**In this adapter variable in the onResponse getting null Why?**

Comment: could you explain your intended logic flow?

Comment: I set adapter in oncreatevew of my fragment. I am also calling network function in that method. The response is getting on the fragment

Comment: the endpoint your hitting did you debug it, to validate the backened actually sending back data

Comment: @Remario yea... I debugged it

Comment: results, on the server side, ok?

Comment: There is no connection between serverside and code with adapter @Remario

Answer (score 0):

Last I found it

Actually I am calling `MyTransactionFragment()::onResponse` in subscriber. which means I am putting the result on the new instance of `MyTransactionFragment`. So I changed this to

```
disposable.add(mApiSocket!!.transaction(""+page+1)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(::onResponse,::onError))
```